Create a pool of Viewholders for Recycler View
I am using 2 fragments , in the first fragment i have giving some options to the user to select from , after that second fragment will be created . Second fragment contains a recycler view , each recycler view item is  quite complex and have some nesting . Problem is whenever i am going from Fragment A to Fragment B , i can see some framedrops, on inspection i came to know , recycler view is taking a lot of time for inflating these items.
i tried asyc layout inflation , it was working good, but when i open frag B for the first time it shows little bit of a lag , after that (when i back press and reopen frag B ) it make a smooth transition means no prob of inflation. But  i am thinking when app starts , i can create a pool of viewholder for like  10-12 items , and directly supply these items to the recycler view rather than letting recycler view inflat these items on its own, on ui threads one by one . i am finding this quite diff to implement , so i want your help guys.

Does this help? https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#recyclerview_nested_recyclerviews
